# Add Multiple locations to mysql row and then query it

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, search, location

I have a project which requires us to store service providers that we can then search for by locations.

We need to store the **province, city, area** and some have particular areas they will only operate in.

We store the locations to MySQL in an imploded array.

We receive a lead that we need to search for contractors to provice a service the problem is however that a contractor can opperate on an entire city or only in a single area. How would you accuratly assign locations to the contractors and then search them.

**Example:**

Contractor1:
Locations: Gauteng, Johannesburg West

Contractor2:
Locations: Gauteng, Johannesburg West, Roodepoort

Contractor3:
Locations: Gauteng, Johannesburg

How would you accurately search for contractors with the leads address being Gauteng, Johannesburg West, Roodepoort, Wilro Park, as all 3 contractors should be returned.

Thanks for any help/advice in advance.

Comment: Look into Haversine formula and storing GPS coords of each location, then you can do distance checks easily.

Comment: Can you provide your table structure with some sample data it will be easy to understand your requirement.